# second order equation in space of distribution D'

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

We consider the equation 
$$
2xT''−T'=\delta, \forall x > 0.
$$
where $\delta$ is Dirac in zero.

1. I begin to solve the homogeneous equation 
   $$
   2 x T'' - T'= 0
   $$
   we put $T=x^r$, then we found general solution 
   $$
   T_h= C_1+C_2 x^2,
   $$
   where 
   $C_1$ and $C_2$ are real.

My question is: how we can found an particular solution for this non homogeneous equation? without Fourier transforma. Please

Comment: Since this is a linear equation, I would try taking the Fourier transform (which is well defined in the sense of distributions). Also, the Fourier transform of the Dirac $\delta$ is quite nice (I am assuming $\delta$ is the Dirac delta at zero).

Comment: there exist an methode to found particular solution without Fourier transform? Please

Comment: Try to find a particular solution of the form $f(t)H(t)$, where $f\in C^\infty$ and $H$ is the Heavyside function.

Comment: Note that $x^2$ is **not** a solution of the homogeneous equation, but $x^{3/2}$ is.